# Super constructor not working how I think it should

Tags: java, oop, constructor

I have a class:

```
public abstract class LogicGate extends JPanel implements PropertyChangeListener {

    private Image image;
    private URL url;
    private OutputTerminal output;
    private Terminal input0;
    private Terminal input1;

    public LogicGate(String fileName) {
        this.url = getClass().getResource(fileName);
        this.image = new javax.swing.ImageIcon(url).getImage();
        this.setSize(image.getWidth(null), image.getHeight(null));
        this.output = new OutputTerminal();
    }
}
```

and a subclass:

```
public class ANDGate extends LogicGate {

    private OutputTerminal output;
    private Terminal input0;
    private Terminal input1;

    public ANDGate() {
        super("images/AND.gif");
        System.out.println(this.output);
    }
}
```

Yet when I invoke a new `ANDGate` object, `output` is null, when it should have been assigned (as per the super constructor).

Now clearly I have a made an assumption in understanding subclassing constructors; what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This situation is called [field hiding](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/hidevariables.html) - the subclass field `output` is "hiding" the field of the same name in the super class.

You have defined

```
private OutputTerminal output;
```

in both your super class *and* your subclass. References to `output` in the subclass will be to its field, but you're setting output in the super class - the subclass field will remain null.

To fix:

- delete the declaration of `output` in the subclass
- change the declaration of `output` in the super class to `protected` (so the subclass can access it)

Comment: Well that fixed everything. Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

Both  output variables are local each class
they refer to two different members.

you rather remove

```
private OutputTerminal output;
```

from `class ANDGate` and simply use

```
System.out.println(output);
```

Make

```
private OutputTerminal output;
```

`protected` in super class.

Answer (score 1):

You can make the class variable in super class as protected and use 'super' keyword instead of 'this' in the system.out.println() line.

Example code for you.

```
//superclass
class A {
protected int a;

public A(){
    a=50;
}
}

//sublcass
class B extends A{

private int a;

public B(){
    super();
    System.out.println(super.a);
}
```

}